# could not start the command or log file not found

Tags: pdftex, miktex, installing, compiling

[image: compiling error]

I get the error `could not start the command` when compiling with Quickstart and I get `log file not found` when compiling with PDFLaTeX.

Can any one help me with this issue? Please, see the screen shot.

Comment: Naive question: Did you install LaTeX?

Comment: I solved this problem by getting some packages from CTAN